# Every map $S^1 \rightarrow X$ extends to a map $D^2 \rightarrow X$ implies $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is trivial

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology

Every map $S^1 \rightarrow X$ extends to a map $D^2 \rightarrow X$ implies $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is trivial

I know this has been posted before, but I was hoping somebody could verify my proof for me:

Let $[f] \in \pi(X,x_0)$

Then we have $f$ is a map:

$f: I \rightarrow X$
such that
$f(0)=f(1)$

So we can consider $f$ a map from $S^1$ into $X$:

$f: S^1 \rightarrow X$

this map extends to $D^2$ by hypothesis:

$\tilde{f}: D^2 \rightarrow X$ where $S^1 = \delta D^2$

Define a homotopy $H: D^2 \times I \rightarrow X$ by

$((r,\theta),s) \rightarrow \tilde{f}(sr,\theta)$

Then we have:

$H((r,\theta),1)=\tilde{f}(r,\theta)$

$H((r,\theta),0)=\tilde{f}(0,\theta)=c_0$

And we can define $F(\theta,s)=H((1,\theta),s): S^1 \times I \rightarrow X$

So that:

$F(\theta,0)=H((1,\theta),0)=c_0$

$F(\theta,1)=H((1,\theta),1)=f(\theta)$

So that $F$ is a homotopy between $f$ and the constant map, $c_0$, and therefore $[f]=[c_0]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining $F(z,t)=\tilde{f}(tz)$ is not enough because this maps doesn't fixe the base point. Instead you can define $F(z,t)=\tilde{f}((1-t)z+t)$ which satisfies $F(1,\cdot)=x_0$.

**Edit:** I just add a picture to visualize the homotopy.
[image]

Comment: So you are using $z$ instead of $\theta$ where $z$ is between 0 and 1 and parameterizing the circle?

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom no here I just take $z\in S^1$, so with you notations it's something like $z=e^{2\pi i\theta}$. After $(1-t)z+t\in D^2$ is calculated with the usual operations in $\Bbb C$. Is this clear?

Comment: I think so. And we need the base point to be fixed because we are doing more than showing that this map is homotopic to a constant map, we are showing that there is a homotopy to a constant map that fixes the base point because that is what equivalence classes in $\pi(X,x_0)$ look like.

Comment: It's a stranger looking homotopy than I expected, not just like a straight line to the center of the image of $D^2$. You have the part $(1-t)z$ that takes something on $\delta D^2$ and moves it inwards towards the center of $D^2$, and then you have the term $+t$ that in my mind would translate it to the right, as t is a real positive number. Still don't completely have my head wrapped around this but I'll continue thinking about it.

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom for you first message: we are just proving that $f$ and the constant path equal to $x_0$ are equivalent, that is there is a homotopy between these two path fixing the base point. For your second message, note that when $z$ describes $S^1$, $(1-t)z+t$ describes the circle of center $t$ and of radius $(1-t)$, just as in the picture. So the homotopy is just reading $\tilde{f}$ on smaller and smaller circles, each containing $1$ to make the homotopy a basepoint-preserving-homotopy.

Answer (score 0):

Assume every map $f:\mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow X$ extends to a map $g:D^2\rightarrow X$.

Then, $\pi_1(X,x_0)=[(\mathbb{S}^1,s_0),(X,x_0)]=[(D^2,s_0),(X,x_0)]$.